# Perlscript runs fine when executed manually but not under cron

Tags: linux, cron, perl, networkmanager

my wireless setup fails several times a day, restarting gnome's network manager helps. I want to automate this and hacked the following perlscript:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                   

use strict;
use warnings;

my $result = system "ping -c1 -W1 192.168.1.1";

if ($result != 0) {
  print "No connectivity. Action required...\n";
  my $pid = `pgrep nm-applet`;
  if ($pid) {
    print "Killing current nm-applet instance $pid\n";
    system "kill $pid";
  }

  print "Starting nm-applet...";
  exec "nm-applet" or die "couldn't start nm-applet";

} else {
  print "Looks all fine. No action required\n";
}
```

My first test was to just kill nm-applet by hand and running the script manually. It detects no connectivity and just "morphs" into nm-applet, just as intended.

Now the same test but executed by the following cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/joe/netcheck.pl >> /home/joe/netcheck.log &
```

The output in netcheck.log is just "Starting nm-applet..." but it doesn't get started.
The process just dies immediately.

Any help or possibly other solution appreciated.

Comment: #!/us/bin/perl?

Comment: @Rich: Good eye, but I assume that if the script gets as far as "Starting nm-applet...". that's a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone who answered has already pointed out, cron runs commands in a very minimal environment. 
I'd suggest you try this in sequence:

1. Use the full path for any calls made in the script.
2. In the crontab entry, execute the script explicitly using perl.

   > /usr/bin/perl /home/joe/netcheck.pl
3. Capture both *stdout* and *stderr* output of the script.

   > /usr/bin/perl /home/joe/netcheck.pl 1>/home/joe/netcheck-stdout.log 2>/home/joe/netcheck-stderr.log &
4. Temporarily replace `exec "nm-applet"` with `exec "ls"` or some other simple command to check that the problem is with the environment nm-applet expects, not with the script itself.
5. Check if executing `nm-applet –sm-disable` helps.
6. If you're still stuck, execute `strace nm-applet` instead to trace the system calls. Run this normally and within cron to identify the call from which the logs diverge. Debug from that point.

Having said this, I'm not surprised to see nm-applet failing to run properly from within cron. It probably needs access to the display and gnome libraries that are missing from within the cron environment. An at job might be better, but even that isn't ideal. I'd recommand using [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/) instead if you need to reconnect from a cron job.

Comment: nice, i'll check out wicd.

Comment: installed wicd, seems very slick.

Answer (score 1):

Cron runs under a very minimal environment. Supply explicit, full paths for all shell commands (e.g., `/sbin/ping` instead of `ping` and so on - check where the relevant items are first with `whereis ping` and so on), and it will likely run fine.

Comment: Has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't start GUI apps from cron, since cron has no environment, desktop, display, etc.

Try this in cron

```
*/1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/joe/netcheck.pl >> /home/joe/netcheck.log &
```

or instead of setting DISPLAY in the crontab, try setting it in the script itself.  I'm not sure which way will work.

Comment: You might also have to do some tedious mucking about with xauth too.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. I guess the real problem here is that my networking environment is managed by a desktop application..

Answer (score 0):

In your script, try dumping the system PATH before the "exec nm-applet" call.  nm-applet exists in /usr/bin on my system, and I cannot imagine the default PATH not containing /usr/bin but stranger things have happened.

Comment: I changed the exec argument to an absolute path. Doesn't change anything.